# Get mac address of the wifi router my phone is connected to, using flutter

Tags: java, ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have been trying to get the the mac address of my wifi router that my device is connected to. I am using Flutter.

I have come across few plugins like [get_ip](https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip), [wifi_info_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_plugin) and also [flutter_ip](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ip). But either it shows unknown, doesn't support android, doesn't support ios or just shows nothing at all.

What I am trying to do is to make **my app run only** when **connected** to one **specific wifi router**. So basically some features of the app will be disabled when connected to a different wifi router other than mine.

Please suggest any other plugin or any work around.

Comment: You know that MAC address spoofng is trivial right?

Comment: yes, but since this is more like an inhouse app strictly for employees. that is the reason I want few services to be locked to a specific office wifi router.

Answer (score 2):

You can use you `SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork` framework to copy your current network info from the supported interfaces. Note that you would need to allow access your device's location and enable Hotspot Configuration and Access WiFi Information in your app capabilities:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork
import NetworkExtension

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var ssid = ""
    var bssid = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            fetchNetworkInfo()
        } else {
            fetchBSSIDInfo()
        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    @available(iOS, introduced: 4.1.0, deprecated: 14.0)
    func fetchBSSIDInfo()  {
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as? [CFString]  {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let currentNetworkInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface) as? [CFString: Any]  {
                    ssid = currentNetworkInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID] as? String ?? ""
                    print("ssid:", ssid)
                    bssid = currentNetworkInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeyBSSID] as? String ?? ""
                    print("bssid:", bssid)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    func fetchNetworkInfo() {
        NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent { network in
            guard let network = network else { return }
            
            print("The SSID for the Wi-Fi network.")
            print("ssid:", network.ssid, "\n")
            self.ssid = network.ssid

            print("The BSSID for the Wi-Fi network.")
            print("bssid:", network.bssid, "\n")
            self.bssid = network.bssid
            
            print("The recent signal strength for the Wi-Fi network.")
            print("signalStrength:", network.signalStrength, "\n")
            
            print("Indicates whether the network is secure")
            print("isSecure:", network.isSecure, "\n")
            
            print("Indicates whether the network was joined automatically or was joined explicitly by the user.")
            print("didAutoJoin:", network.didAutoJoin, "\n")
            
            print("Indicates whether the network was just joined.")
            print("didJustJoin:", network.didJustJoin, "\n")
            
            print("Indicates whether the calling Hotspot Helper is the chosen helper for this network.")
            print("isChosenHelper:", network.isChosenHelper, "\n")
        }
    }

    @available(iOS, introduced: 13.2.0, deprecated: 14.0)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        didChangeAuthorization(status: status)
    }
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        didChangeAuthorization(status: manager.authorizationStatus)
    }
    func didChangeAuthorization(status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("The user has not chosen whether the app can use location services.\n")
        case .restricted:
            print("The app is not authorized to use location services.\n")
        case .denied:
            print("The user denied the use of location services for the app or they are disabled globally in Settings.\n")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("The user authorized the app to start location services at any time.\n")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("The user authorized the app to start location services while it is in use.\n")
        @unknown default: break
        }
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted, .denied:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Allow Location Access",
                                          message: "Please turn on Location Services",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(.init(title: "Settings",
                                  style: .default) { _ in
                let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url) { success in
                        print("Settings opened: \(success)")
                    }
                }
            })
            alert.addAction(.init(title: "Ok", style: .default))
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        @unknown default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this can get get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: fetchNetworkInfo() returns network object only for few seconds, mostly 4-5 seconds and after that it sends nil object instead of any netwok object.. I am checking in iOS 14... I want SSID information in background...any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I was searching for this answer too.

Refer the code mentioned below.
And enable permission of Location and enable Location too.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  WifiInfoWrapper _wifiObject;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    WifiInfoWrapper wifiObject;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      wifiObject = await WifiInfoPlugin.wifiDetails;
    } on PlatformException {}
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _wifiObject = wifiObject;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String macAddress = _wifiObject != null ? _wifiObject.bssId.toString() : "mac";
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Mac of AP - ' + macAddress),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still have the same error as before, got 02:00:00:00:00:00:00. but now I got 02:00:00:00:00:00:00 in emulator and blank in real device.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [wifi_info_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_plugin) is your best bet.  Follow the documentation, and try to get the AP MAC like so:

```
wifiObject = await  WifiInfoPlugin.wifiDetails;
AP_MAC = wifiObject.bssId.toString();
```

Make sure that `AP_MAC != "missing"`, and wrap in a try/catch in case it throws a `PlatformException`. This may not work for iOS devices.

Comment: I did this too, got 02:00:00:00:00:00:00.

Comment: @takiuddin93 some kind of permission issue don't know how to solve did you find it out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I end up using location package.

```
 location: ^3.0.2


bool _serviceEnabled;
_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
}
```