# Is this Swift code a race condition or is it executing correctly?

Tags: swift, post, core-location, cllocationmanager, dispatch-queue

So, I have a post request in my app which relies on the user latitude and longitude already having a value (0,0 is the default for lat,lon so anything EXCEPT this). I run the post request in my didChangeAuthorizationStatus, but I'm not sure if it's a race condition or if it is executing correctly. Before I wrapped the request in a DispatchQueue.main.async, the user latitude/longitude wasn't set before the request got sent off, but it appears to be working now. I want to deploy this update, but don't know if there's a way to confirm this is the correct implementation:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            //do notDetermined stuff
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // primaryManger is just a CLLocationManager
            primaryManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
            // the line below used to not be wrapped in DispatchQueue.main.async and it seems like wrapping it fixed the issue of lat/lon not being set before the post request was sent off, not sure though
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.functionMaster.postRequest()
            }
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            primaryManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.functionMaster.postRequest()
            }
            break
        case .restricted:
            //do restricted stuff
            break
        case .denied:
            //do denied stuff
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

So, postRequest() should only be called after

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // setting of user location happens here
}
```

is called.

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what is supposed to be happening. Are you saying that `postRequest` should only be called *after* a location is set (which presumably only happens once `startUpdatingLocation` is called and its callback is fired?

Comment: @jnpdx Just updated the question, but yes.

Comment: In that case, `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not a robust/foolproof solution, then. It *may* be called after the first location is set or it *may* be called before. Instead, you should probably have some sort of boolean flag you can set the first time you set a location value and then call `postRequest()` when you change that value.

Comment: @nickcoding2 this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218753/2303865